# Looking for a LED transmitter/receiver package(or group of components)

Tags: led, transmitter, feedback, receiver

I am trying to design a system that utilizes 355nm and 370nm LEDs. I want to keep their intensity stabilized at a certain value, so I want to create a feedback loop. I am using these LEDs as individual transmitters, and want to use an additional receiver adjacent to each transmitter LED to sample the intensity of the LED for the feedback loop. My question is, are there any LED packages out there with a built in transmitter/feedback receiver pair?

If this sounds confusing, below is a diagram the package I need

((LED)(Feedback Reciever)Package) -------------transmission medium------------ (Reciever)

Comment: Yes, they have to be UV. I also forgot to mention, the LED is not a super high powered LED(I do not know the intensity rating off the top of my head), and it needs to be a laser LED.

Answer (score 1):

These packages do exist but are often in the Infrared range: ~950nm rather than on the UV range. For example:

https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/QR/QRE1113.pdf

You can look for them as "optical switches".

Do you specifically need them in the UV range? UV photodetectors tend to be more expensive and you have less options.

Comment: Yes, they have to be UV. I also forgot to mention, the LED is not a super high powered LED(I do not know the intensity rating off the top of my head), and it needs to be a laser LED.